# Loop URL list and save as txt file

Tags: python

I have a URL as follows: https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=1. I want to create a file named `list_of_urls.txt` which contains url links from `p=1` to `p=20`, seperate each with space, and save it as a txt file.

Here is what I have tried, but it only prints the last one:

```
url = "https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p="
list_of_urls = []
for page in range(20):
    list_of_urls = url + str(page)
print(list_of_urls)
```

The expected txt file inside would be like this:
[image]

Comment: Try `list_of_urls.append(url + str(page))` instead. To start with at least. Because right now you're replacing the list every iteration.

Comment: Many thanks to all the helps and comments! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the occasion to use *f-strings*, usable since Python 3.6, and fully described in [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```
url_base = "https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p="

with open('your.txt', 'w') as f:
    for page in range(1, 20 + 1):
        f.write(f'{url_base}{page} ')
       #f.write('{}{} '.format(url_base, page))
       #f.write('{0}{1} '.format(url_base, page))
       #f.write('{u}{p} '.format(u=url_base, p=page))
       #f.write('{u}{p} '.format(**{'u':url_base, 'p':page}))
       #f.write('%s%s '%(url_base, page))
```

Notice the *space character* at the end of each formatting expression.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with `range` - it starts from from `0` by default and the last number of the range is not included. Hence, if you want numbers `1 - 20` you need to use `range(1, 21)`.

```
url_template = "https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p={page}"
urls = [url_template.format(page=page) for page in range(1, 21)]

with open("/tmp/urls.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(" ".join(urls))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
url = "https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p="
list_of_urls = ""
for page in range(20):
    list_of_urls = list_of_urls + url + str(page) + " "
print(list_of_urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want *one line* inside your file but if so:

```
url = "https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=%i"
with open("expected.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(' '.join([url %i for i in range(1,21)]))
```

Output:

```
https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=1 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=2 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=3 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=4 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=5 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=6 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=7 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=8 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=9 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=10 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=11 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=12 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=13 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=14 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=15 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=16 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=17 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=18 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=19 https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=20
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also work, thanks to my colleague!

```
url = "https://www.vq.com/36851082/?p=%d"
result = " ".join([ url % (x + 1) for x in range(20)])
with open("list_of_urls.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```